# Datewise grouping data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have sample dataframe:

```
date            item1    item2    item3
17-11-2016      2A        hp       cnf
12-11-2016      1A        bp       wl
13-11-2016      3A        sp       dl
14-11-2016      1A        hp       cnf
16-11-2016      2A        bp       cnf
10-11-2016      1A        sp       wl
17-11-2016      2A        hp       wl
```

I want to group data based on all columns date, item1 and item2, so that particular column with same value will come to same group.

Expected output:

```
date            item1    item2    item3    grp
17-11-2016      2A        hp       cnf      1
17-11-2016      2A        hp       wl       1
12-11-2016      1A        bp       wl       2
13-11-2016      3A        sp       dl       3
14-11-2016      1A        hp       cnf      4
16-11-2016      2A        bp       cnf      5
10-11-2016      1A        sp       wl       6
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Are you just referring to sorting the data?

Comment: @akaDrHouse, this is not sorting prob, but want to group based on same col values.

Comment: Your input dataset seems to have a different order of 'date' than the expected output (it is not following any sorting pattern though).  How did it got changed.  I was using the expected data to create the 'grp' column.

Comment: @ akrun can we sort all col based on date first, then try to grp. can you plz tell me how to do it.

Comment: @azad You need to convert to `Date` class and sort it i.e. `df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, "%d-%m-%Y"); df1 <- df1[order(df1$date),]` and then create the grp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
DF <- data.frame(date = c("17-11-2016","12-11-2016","13-11-2016","14-11-2016",
                          "16-11-2016","10-11-2016","17-11-2016"),
                 item1 = c("2A","1A","3A","1A","2A","1A","2A"),
                 item2 = c("hp","bp","sp","hp","bp","sp","hp"),
                 item3 = c("cnf","wl","dl","cnf","cnf","wl","wl")
                 )
DF$grp <- as.numeric(factor(paste(DF$date,DF$item1,DF$item2)))
DF[order(DF$grp),]
        date item1 item2 item3 grp
6 10-11-2016    1A    sp    wl   1
2 12-11-2016    1A    bp    wl   2
3 13-11-2016    3A    sp    dl   3
4 14-11-2016    1A    hp   cnf   4
5 16-11-2016    2A    bp   cnf   5
7 17-11-2016    2A    hp    wl   6
1 17-11-2016    2A    hp   cnf   6
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `paste` the first three columns, convert to `factor` by specifying the `levels` as the `unique` elements in the 'v1' and coerce it to `integer`

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, df1[1:3])
df1$grp <- as.integer(factor(v1, levels = unique(v1)))
df1$grp
#[1] 1 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Or use `match`

```
match(v1, unique(v1))
#[1] 1 1 2 3 4 5 6
```